# Don't know how Collider works in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, collider

I'm using a collider script to end the game when it hits an object. The code i have used is not working. Please help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class Collider : MonoBehaviour {


    void OnTriggerEvent(Collider other){
        Debug.Log (other.tag);
        if (other.tag == "Wall") {
            Debug.Log ("collided");
        //  Application.LoadLevel ("level one");
            SceneManager.LoadScene (2);

        } if (other.tag == "End"){ 
            SceneManager.LoadScene(6);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening when it collides? Does the log has any information? Is the event called at all?

Comment: Not working? So what does happen then? Nothing? Something? The end of the known universe?  How do you expect anyone to answer if you do not even provide the relevant details?

Comment: Do you have a collider attached to your GameObject? Also: if you can avoid it, you shouldn't name your classes like ones that are native to unity (because of shadowing)

Comment: Nothing happens. Log does not have any info. It is suppose to load that particular scene when it collides. but it just passes through the object. Doesn't collide.

Comment: Yes i have attached collider to the GameObject. I also have a javascript collider that works perfectly. Only the C# is not working

Comment: I have put a spehere collider to my gameobject. Also, changed the Script name. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I think you misspelled the function name, it sould be `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` instead of OnTrigger**Event**. That's why it is not called when collision events occure.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: Can you have more than one OnTriggerEnter methods? Because i have multiple tags for different triggering events. Such as going to the next level by colliding with one object and colliding with another object to end the game

Comment: No you cannot have multiple OnTriggerEnter methods, you have to use if statements to handle different collision events